# How to make an app's view update automatically when a row's column variable is changed in MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, spring, firebase, spring-boot

I am developing an app.
I have developed a spring server with MySQL.
And succeeded connecting the app to my server using Retrofit2.
I know how to send and get data using `@GET` and `@POST`.
But in my app, in an activity, a `TextView` should be changed automatically.

If a user clicks a button, let's say it's a button that purchases a lottery,
And then, the lottery's prize should be updated and everybody should see its changing.

Like, that `TextView` is connected to a single variable, a column of a row of a table.
I can do update that `TextView` when I restart the activity or click a refresh button.

But how can I update that automatically?

How can I change User A's view when User B purchases a lottery without doing anything?

Should I use firebase though I already have a spring boot - MySQL server?
or Room Database and send queries to MySQL server?
or is there any way that MySQL triggers an android's specific methods?

Can FCM (Firebase Cloud Message) trigger methods or activities not only send a push message?

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: MySQL have no any service which allows to notify the client about data is changed. You must do it by your code - requery the data periodically and check it for changes. It can be some procedure in the client code or some service local to MySQL which checks the data periodically and pushes the notification to the client that the data was changed and must be requeried/refreshed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going with [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) seems a better approach to me. 
**The flow will be as follows:**

- Whenever any change happens in MYSQL write some [triggers](https://www.siteground.com/kb/mysql-triggers-use/) for it.
- This [Trigger](https://www.siteground.com/kb/mysql-triggers-use/) can generate the FCM push notification and update the users which you need to update.
- On the App side, receives the notification and retrieve the updated details.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you!! So that fcm can do trigger a method of a view model right? That was the answer I wanted to hear!

Comment: yes exactly from that you can trigger method of viewmodel.